# Sharing dotfiles with the root user

Tags: linux, shell, root, sudo, dotfiles

### Current method

Actually, I'm sharing some of my dotfiles with the root user using **symbolic links**:

```
ln -s ~user/.vimrc  /root/
ln -s ~user/.zshenv /root/
ln -s ~user/.zlogin /root/
ln -s ~user/.zshrc  /root/
```

### Former method

Before, I was using the **sudo** command with the **-E** which preserves the environment. So, the root user, when in an interactive shell, use the standard user home directory and read the corresponding dotfiles.

It works, **but** :

1. Some files may be created in the standard user directory with root as owner
2. Some commands does not allow (or warn me) using files on directory which the owner is not the current user (it's obviously for security reasons). So, executing those commands as root is problematic.

### Better method ?

The simplest method is to put shared settings in the system-wide configuration files (/etc/zshrc, /etc/vimrc).

But I want to keep all the settings in my home directory, where I can keep them synchronized with a Git remote repository. This way, I can deploy them easily on a new computer.

As my current method is tedious and the former was pleasant but problematic,
is there a better method to make root use my current configuration file ?

Comment: Are you crazy??? You opened a big security hole. I mean, seriously, you want to allow a normal user to change `$PATH` for root? To name just an example.

Comment: You're right. I should mention that I only use those configuration files on my personal computer, **not on any server**, and that there is a unique standard user with a password (not any autologin). But anyway, you're right. I should use a deploy script which also deploy them for root (by calling _sudo_, so asking for a password) by copying them (no symlink).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is to include a deployment script in the git repository. I then invoke that script using sudo. The script then runs with root credentials and updates the dotfiles, either in the root account or globally.

I keep the install script as light as possible with no dependencies beyond shell and the core utilities (so no `rsync`).

Comment: Currently, I don't use any deploy script for my dotfiles. All my home directory is versioned. But my .gitignore ignore all files by default and I add them selectively by adding negating patterns.

As your solution seems elegant, maybe I will use a deploy script. If not any other answer gives a better solution, I will accept yours.